# Powershell executing a cmd which executes another cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a Powershell script which calls a build script batch file in order to set up a project. The build script in turn calls another batch file.

```
setup-Environment.ps1
FullRebuild.cmd
GetSource.cmd
```

Powershell script

```
Invoke-Expression -command FullRebuild.cmd
```

FullRebuld.cmd script calls GetSource with a version number parameter

```
GetSource 10.1.0
```

I am getting the following error in powershell:

```
FullRebuild.cmd : 'GetSource' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Comment: Try using full paths everywhere.

Comment: Also, it is not totally clear, but is GetSource a cmd/bat file? If so be sure to use the extension.

Comment: @EBGreen GetSource is a cmd file GetSource.cmd.

Comment: Seems like `FullRebuild.cmd` changes the working directory. We won't know without seeing the actual code in it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the cmd scripts live in the same location the powershell script was running under a different location (my user directory) and therefore the second script did not exist in the context of my user directory.

I have changed my powershell script to `Set-Location` to the location of the cmd scripts. this then works fine.

I could not edit the cmd scripts to use pull paths as suggested by @arco444 as they are maintained by a different team.